# BackgroundService Graceful Shutdown - Complete work and write to DB

Tags: c#, .net, background-service

I have a Background Worker implementing the BackgroundService (provided by MS).

See this simple implementation:

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService {

    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyService(MyDbContext context) {
        //...
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try {
            while (true)
            {
                stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                // Do some work
            }
        } catch(OperationCancelledException) {
            _context.Add(new MyLogMessage(){ Error = "MyService cancelled!" });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

When the graceful shutdown (in console: CTRL+C) is requested the catch block is triggered, and also the `SaveChanges()` seems to be executed. But, sometimes the error is stored into the database and the most of the time it is not. Also the EntityFramework is printing an insert statement on the console, but the log is not in the db.
I assume that the shutdown is happening faster then writting the data to the DB?
Can anyone give me a hint how to handle this situation and store the error into the database?

Comment: What kind of work are you doing in the place of the `// Do some work` placeholder? Is it cancelable? What is its average duration?

Comment: For instance, sending files per http rest. So it can be cancelled and continued when the service starts again. I'd like to have a log message in the database that it was cancelled during a file transfer for instance.

Comment: I guess, I found the problem here. All the answers helped me! Also, the shutdown timeout was extended to 10 seconds, for the moment. The problem was the inconsistent usage of async/await methods in the project itself. Due to this the exception was eaten by a thread an didn't made it all the way up to the ExecuteAsync method. The registered callback for the cancellation token is a helpful thing here and is working like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the `stoppingToken` isn't cancelled as expected when the application shuts down. I managed to get around this using `IHostApplicationLifetime` and a new field where I can store if a shutdown is in progress.

```cs
public class TestService : BackgroundService {
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    private readonly ILogger<TestService> _logger;

    private bool _shutownRequested;

    public TestService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime, ILogger<TestService> logger) {
        _lifetime = lifetime;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        _lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnShutdown() {
        _shutdownRequested = true;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        try {
            while(true) {
                stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                if(_shutdownRequested) {
                    throw new OperationCanceledException();
                }

                await Task.Delay(100, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        } catch(OperationCanceledException) {
            _logger.LogWarning("TestService canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it might be better to now throw a new exception there, but as an example it will do.

Comment: What if we do while(true){stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // more work here...} this should give us an exception?

Comment: Yes that should make is so that you always go to the catch-clause.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, edited the question. The catch block is executed now, but the log message is not always persisted into the db (also an insert statement is printed on the console by the EF, when I press CTRL+C).

Comment: Pressing CTRL+C once should trigger a graceful shutdown, if you press it again the application will be forcefully terminated. It seem like the stoppingToken isn't cancelled as expected though. I did some tests and came up with a solution using IHostApplicationLifetime instead. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the log entry doesn't appear in the database is that the host shutdown period is lower than what it takes to process a task in a `while` loop and send a log to the database. The default timeout is 5 seconds.

What you could do, is to increase the timeout to a larger value, for example a minute a two:

```
services.Configure<HostOptions>(
    opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Make sure to let enough time for a service to finish the iteration inside a `while` loop and log the message.

Please check [Extending the shutdown timeout setting to ensure graceful IHostedService shutdown](https://andrewlock.net/extending-the-shutdown-timeout-setting-to-ensure-graceful-ihostedservice-shutdown/) for more details.